# How can I remove rows from a numpy array that have NaN as the first element?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
 [[nan 0 0 ..., 0.0 0.053526738 0.068421053]
 [nan 0 0 ..., 0.0 0.059653990999999996 0.068421053]
 [nan 0 0 ..., 1.0 0.912542592 0.068421053]
 ..., 
 [1 0 0 ..., 0.0 0.126523399 0.193548387]
 [nan 0 0 ..., 0.0 0.034388807 0.068421053]
 [4 0 0 ..., 0.0 0.02250561 0.068421053]]
```

How do I remove all rows from the array where nan is the first element?

Comment: Use ```numpy.isnan``` to test the first element of of each row.  Combine that with ```numpy.where``` to return the rows you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If x is the original array, the following puts the valid rows into y:

```
y = x[~np.isnan(x[:, 0])]
```